# Scrapping my Linkedin job post to obtain a candidates emails list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, linkedin-api

Im trying to obtain the candidate's email from the "More..." button which has a dropdown and second element is the email. The dropdown options don't have html structure. Now I'm trying an approach using js but I can't figure it out. Thank you!!

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Replace the path with the actual path to your Chrome user data directory
user_data_dir = xxxxxxxxxx

# Replace the profile name with the actual profile name you want to use
profile_name = xxxxxxx

# Set the Chrome options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={user_data_dir}')
options.add_argument(f'--profile-directory={profile_name}')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')  # Add the remote debugging port argument

# Set the Chrome service
service = Service('C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')

# Create a new Chrome driver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# URL of the candidate's profile on LinkedIn Hiring
profile_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/hiring/jobs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# Load the candidate's profile on LinkedIn Hiring
driver.get(profile_url)

# Click on the "More..." button using JavaScript
more_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'More')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", more_button)

# Wait for the email element to appear
time.sleep(2)  # Add a short delay to allow the element to load

try:
    # Find the email element by its class name and click on it using JavaScript
    email_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "pv-contact-info__contact-link")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", email_element)
    print("Clicked on the email element.")
except:
    print("Email element not found or unable to click on it.")

# Close the Selenium webdriver
driver.quit()
```

I would like to fix my code. Always print "Email element not found or unable to click on it" but the email is there. `

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with Java.

Comment: Not every person there has access to https://www.linkedin.com/hiring/jobs/ , you should provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: this looks old... `service = Service('C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')`